# How to change contact from 7 spinning arrow location?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i have used [Contact from 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) in my WordPress Theme, there are lot of options but i did not find any option to change the location of the (loading/ spinning arrow).

i want to display loading arrow on the Top of contact from.

Comment: let me check, it disappears in seconds how i have to catch it?

Comment: @NabilKadimi yes its an image !

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old but maybe somebody still needs an answer.

To override the ajax loader the right thing to do is to filter out the CF7 php function wpcf7_ajax_loader with a custom one.

Just place this function inside functions.php inside your theme and you should be good.

```
# Override ajax loader
add_filter('wpcf7_ajax_loader', 'custom_wpcf7_ajax_loader');
function custom_wpcf7_ajax_loader () {
    return  get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/custom-ajax-loader.gif';
}
```